# Total = print(Subtotal + Tax + Tip) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
meal_cost = 10.00
tax_rate = 0.08
tip_rate = 0.20

#You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them!
#When you Submit your code, we'll change these lines to
#assign different values to the variables.
 
#When eating at a restaurant in the United States, it's
#customary to have two percentage-based surcharges added on
#top of your bill: sales tax and tip. These percentages are
#both applies to the original cost of the meal. For example,
#a 10.00 meal with 8% sales tax and 20% tip would add 0.80
#for tax (0.08 * 10.00) and 2.00 for tip (0.20 * 10.00).
#
#The variables above create the cost of a meal and identify
#what percentage should be charged for tax and tip.
#
#Add some code below that will print the "receipt" for a
#meal purchase. The receipt should look like this:
#
#Subtotal: 10.00
#Tax: 0.8
#Tip: 2.0
#Total: 12.8
#
#Subtotal is the original value of meal_cost, tax is the
#tax rate times the meal cost, the tip is the tip rate times
#the meal cost, and the total is the sum of all three numbers.
#Don't worry about the number of decimal places; it's fine
#if your code leaves off some numbers (like 0.8 for tax) or
#includes too many decimal places (like 2.121212121 for the tip).

 
#Add your code here!


Subtotal = print(float(meal_cost))
Tax= print(float(tax_rate*10))
Tip = print(float(tip_rate *100))
Total = print(Subtotal + Tax + Tip)
```

```
    Total = print(Subtotal + Tax + Tip) 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Why am I getting this error in spite of the fact that I have converted everything to float?

Why adding float is causing such errors?

Comment: You're assigning the value returned from print, which is None. Also your calculations are wrong.

Comment: I didn't get your comment

regarding calculation; I know Tip should be multiplied by 10 instead of 100

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign statements with print()

Plus, your variables are already float, you don't need to put them inside float()

Do this:

```
Subtotal = meal_cost
Tax= tax_rate*10
Tip = tip_rate*100
Total = Subtotal + Tax + Tip
print(Total)
```

However, if you want to print and at the same time assign variables inside print() (i don't reccomend this), you can use the walrus operator:

```
print(Subtotal := meal_cost)
print(Tax := tax_rate*10)
print(Tip := tip_rate*100)

print(Subtotal + Tax + Tip)
```

Comment: Your code will result in the following error: 
Total = (Subtotal + Tax + Tip)
TypeError: must be str, not float

Comment: @user11052359 that's not possible, unless you're trying to add Total to a string (to print it maybe). if so, you can convert it with str(Total), `print(str(Total) + "is the total")`; or simply `print("total is:", Total)` without converting it

Comment: Formulae provided was incorrrect!

Answer (score 0):

```
meal_cost = 10.00
tax_rate = 0.08
tip_rate = 0.20
```

> #You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them!
> #When you Submit your code, we'll change these lines to
> #assign different values to the variables.
>
> #When eating at a restaurant in the United States, it's
> #customary to have two percentage-based surcharges added on
> #top of your bill: sales tax and tip. These percentages are
> #both applies to the original cost of the meal. For example,
> #a 10.00 meal with 8% sales tax and 20% tip would add 0.80
> #for tax (0.08 * 10.00) and 2.00 for tip (0.20 * 10.00).
>
> #The variables above create the cost of a meal and identify
> #what percentage should be charged for tax and tip.
>
> #Add some code below that will print the "receipt" for a
> #meal purchase. The receipt should look like this:
>
> #Subtotal: 10.00
> #Tax: 0.8
> #Tip: 2.0
> #Total: 12.8
>
> #Subtotal is the original value of meal_cost, tax is the
> #tax rate times the meal cost, tip is the tip rate times
> #the meal cost, and total is the sum of all three numbers.
> #Don't worry about the number of decimal places; it's fine
> #if your code leaves off some numbers (like 0.8 for tax) or
> #includes too many decimal places (like 2.121212121 for tip).
>
> #Add your code here!

```
Subtotal = meal_cost            
Tax = tax_rate* meal_cost
Tip = tip_rate*meal_cost
Total = (Subtotal + Tax + Tip)
print("Subtotal:", Subtotal)
print("Tax:", Tax)
print("Tip:", Tip)
print("Total:", Total)
```

**Solved it . Thanks for guidance**